# Template literals, Font Awesome, chessboard.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome, chessboard.js

I'm creating a chess game using the CSS and JS libraries for chessboard.js and chess.js. For some reason chessboard.js was unable to access its chess piece images, so I decided to use the icons that are on awesome font. For some reason I'm getting a 404 error from | return '`; |. Here's all my code:

```js
var board, game = new Chess();

// Custom piece theme using Font Awesome icons
function pieceTheme(piece) {
  // Map chess.js piece codes to Font Awesome icons
  var pieceToIcon = {
    'p': 'fas fa-chess-pawn',
    'r': 'fas fa-chess-rook',
    'n': 'fas fa-chess-knight',
    'b': 'fas fa-chess-bishop',
    'q': 'fas fa-chess-queen',
    'k': 'fas fa-chess-king'
  };

  var pieceClass = pieceToIcon[piece.charAt(1).toLowerCase()];
  var colorClass = piece.charAt(0) === 'w' ? 'text-white' : 'text-black';
  return `<span class="${pieceClass} ${colorClass}"></span>`;
}

// Configuration object for chessboard.js
var config = {
  draggable: true,
  position: 'start',
  pieceTheme: pieceTheme,
  onDragStart: onDragStart,
  onDrop: onDrop,
  onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
};

// Initialize the chessboard with the configuration
board = Chessboard('chessboard', config);

// Event listener for drag start
function onDragStart(source, piece, position, orientation) {
  // Don't pick up pieces if the game is over
  if (game.game_over()) return false;

  // Only pick up pieces of the current turn
  if ((game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
      (game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Event listener for drop
function onDrop(source, target) {
  // Attempt to make a move
  var move = game.move({
    from: source,
    to: target,
    promotion: 'q' // NOTE: Always promote to a queen for simplicity
  });

  // If the move is illegal, return 'snapback' to reset the piece
  if (move === null) return 'snapback';
}

// Event listener for snap end
function onSnapEnd() {
  // Update the board position after the piece snap
  board.position(game.fen());
}
```

```css
#chessboard {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

/* Adjust the size of the font awesome icons to fit the squares */
.chessboard .square-55d63 .piece-417db {
  font-size: 2em; /* Example size, adjust as needed */
}

/* Use !important to enforce color styling on Font Awesome icons */
.fa-chess-pawn, .fa-chess-rook, .fa-chess-knight, .fa-chess-bishop, .fa-chess-queen, .fa-chess-king {
  color: inherit !important;
}

/* Custom color classes for chess pieces */
.text-white { color: white !important; }
.text-black { color: black !important; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Chess</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.10.3/chess.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">


    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="chessboard" style="margin: auto;"></div>
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me how to get the images from chessboard.js library or can someone fix the code I gave above using the awesome font icons. Thank you!

Comment: look at what the chessboard library is doing with your `<span`s ... trying to use the span as an `<img src` - clearly not going to work - the documentation states `the function should return an <img> source.` - which yours does not

Comment: if you [download the library](https://chessboardjs.com/download) - you won't need to faff around with figuring out where to get chess piece images from

Comment: If you inspect one of the broken images using the console tools you see `<img src="<span class=" fas="" fa-chess-knight="" text-black"="">` which is clearly nonsense